# sql sequence start with value taken from another sequencer

Tags: sql, plsql, sequence

I need to drop a sequencer and create a another with a starting value of the last sequencer. hard coding the starting value is not an option.

```
DECLARE

    NxtVal INTEGER;

BEGIN
    SELECT  (SEQ1.NEXTVAL)+10
        into NxtVal
        From Dual;


    execute immediate  'Create sequence SEQ2
        minvalue 1
        maxvalue 99999
        start with || NxtVal ||
        increment by 1';
END;
/
```

Comment: So does this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there are some `'` missing:

```
DECLARE
    NxtVal INTEGER;

BEGIN
    SELECT  (SEQ1.NEXTVAL)+10
        into NxtVal
        From Dual;


    execute immediate  'Create sequence SEQ2 '
        'minvalue 1 '
        'maxvalue 99999 '
        'start with ' || NxtVal || -- missing ' 
        ' increment by 1';
END;
/
```

Comment: I would also recommend using `seq1.currval + 10`, leaving the first sequence unaltered.

Comment: @TommCatt: keep in mind that `seq1.currval` only works if you ran `seq1.next` in the current session .... (check for instance this site: http://psoug.org/definition/currval.htm)

Comment: Yes, I had completely forgotten that. Still, all we see is a little test code. He could well have been using the existing sequence before having to create a new one.